# Process input according to array type

Tags: php, object, foreach

I am trying to load arrays onto an object. The arrays can either be a single array or an array of arrays (indicating a number of inputs to be run). The code I have so far is below. Is there a simpler way to call a single method and determine if it should be processed as a single load or a looped load?

```
public function addInput($input) {
    $this->inputs[] .= new Input($input);
}

public function addInputs($matrix_of_inputs) {
    foreach($matrix_of_inputs as $input) {
        $this->inputs[] .= new Input($input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function addInput($input)
{
    $this->inputs[] = new Input($input); // note that I have removed the dot .=
}

public function addInputs($matrix)
{
    if (!is_array($matrix)) {
        $this->addInput($matrix);
        return;
    }

    foreach($matrix as $input) {
        if (is_array($input)) {
            $this->addInputs($input);  // if it can be multidimensional, might not be needed
            continue;
        }
        $this->addInput($matrix);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... is there a reason that array_merge() doesn't work here (as shown in my response)?

Comment: @ConradShultz OP wants the inputs to be an instance of `Input`. He made a typo (or error) with the extra dot. And I thought it would be nice to show off it can handle multidimesional arrays ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addInputs($inputs) {
    array_merge((array)$this->inputs, (array)$inputs);
}
```